# один и тот же файл jquery

Tags: javascript, html, кэширование

подскажите в чем проблема, делаю экспорт (через ajax отправляю данные)
удаляю старый файл и в конце формирую заново файл, но имя одно и тоже

после экспорта отправляю файл на скачивание

```
window.open('https://kristroom.ru/assets/'+data, '_blank');
```

на скачивание отдает файл с одними и теми данными, если захожу на сервер, там в этом файле другие новые данные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кеш. У вас браузер видит, что файл с таким именем он уже скачивал и вместо скачивания отдает вам текущий.

Чтобы убрать кеширование, нужно обеспечить уникальность имени файла. Например, так

```
window.open('https://kristroom.ru/assets/' + data + '?id=' + new Date().valueOf(), '_blank');
```